# git - when working on a branch (new feat), do I pull in updates or merge them?

Tags: git

Let's say there's an `origin/develop` branch. I've branched off that into `feat-whatever` locally (doesn't exist on the server yet) and am working on that branch. If I want to update my branch with anything the team has done, do I do this (while on the `feat-whatever` branch):

```
git pull origin develop
```

or

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout feat-whatever
git merge develop
```

Answer (score 3):

They're both equivalent, since a `pull` is just a `fetch` followed by a `merge`. Well, there is one difference...the second method updates your local `develop` branch, while the first one won't.

You also have the option of rebasing your feature branch to synchronize it with upstream changes:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout feat-whatever
git rebase origin/develop
```

Comment: Ok. I thought there was some warning somewhere about pulling into a branch from another branch..? I forget where I saw it. Basically if you're in branch `feat-whatever`, to not do a pull from `master` or some other branch that's not `feat-whatever`. Maybe I'm confused. :)

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack there's no real extra risk with pulling a non-upstream  branch than there is with pulling from the upstream branch. It just might be more likely to result in a merge commit when doing so ("merged origin/develop into feat-whatever").

Comment: And if we're talking equivalents, the example above is equivalent to `git pull --rebase origin develop`.

Comment: What is the advantage of a rebase vs a merge?

Comment: This might be worth a read (there are many with similar content, but this one makes the best points IMO): http://darwinweb.net/articles/the-case-for-git-rebase

Comment: Rebase allows you to write your history the way you want it. In this particular case, it allows you keep your history simple and easy to read by avoiding creating merge commits. You can think of it as "pushing your branch forward in time", as if you had just started working on it. People tend to dislike merge commits in the case of synchronizing feature branches because they aren't related to the feature. If you just merge all the time and frequently, you "pollute" the history of your feature branch with merge commits, making it harder to understand.

Comment: The one advantage of a merge vs a rebase, however, is that a merge won't rewrite your history, so if you've shared your branch with other people who may base work off of it, it should be safe to merge, but it's usually not a good thing to rebase, since it could possibly be difficult for other people to re-synchronize their work with the new rewritten history.

Comment: Please learn more about [rebasing from the FREE online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html), as well as [the chapter on rewriting history](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). If you can afford it, [Code School has a good explanation for rebase in lesson 6 of their Git Real course too](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/git-real).